# Move center matplotlib table position when turning off axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The following table is not located center because of `ax.axis('off')`. I want to move the table left bottom a little bit. How can I do that?

- output image (the white rectangle is result.png)

[image]

- code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import six

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = ['XXX_1', 'XXX_2', 'XXX_3', 'XXX_4',
           'XXX_5', 'XXX_6', 'XXX_7', 'XXX_8', 'XXX_9']
df['B'] = ['26,540', '1,072', '27,612', '2,975',
           '24,637', '20,000', '4,637', '(1,626)', '27,612']


def set_align_for_column(table, col, align="left"):
    cells = [key for key in table._cells if key[1] == col]
    for cell in cells:
        table._cells[cell]._loc = align


def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.4, font_size=12,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0, **kwargs):

    size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])
            ) * np.array([col_width, row_height])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)

    ax.axis('off')

    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, cellLoc=['left', 'right'],
                         colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    set_align_for_column(mpl_table, col=0, align="left")
    set_align_for_column(mpl_table, col=1, align="right")

    for k, cell in six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
            cell._loc = 'center'
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0] % len(row_colors)])

    return fig


fig = render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)
fig.suptitle('TITLE_ABC', fontsize=18, y=0.97)
fig.savefig('result.png', dpi=300)
```

---

Update 1

I created again using the way suggested by @Yo_Chris

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `bbox_inches` set to `'tight'` and then whatever you want the padding around the image to be. I just chose .5 inches as an example. Here is the [savefig documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html#matplotlib-pyplot-savefig)

```
fig.savefig('result.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=.5)
```